# Is it possible to run a flash memory dump from a production device inside of an emulator/simulator for offline debugging?

Tags: embedded, mips, emulation, embedded-linux, firmware

I am not sure if this is the right forum, or if it would be better suited in a different SE sub, though I figure this is an appropriate place for it.

I am wondering if there are any emulators that are capable of running a flash dump directly that targets the same architecture on the device it was dumped from? So for instance, if the dump was taken from a device(via JTAG) running a Broadcom MIPS CPU, and it contained the entire system(bootloader, firmware, filesystem, NVRAM, etc.) is there anything where I could mount(or should I say, load it into memory) the raw image directly, memory and all, and run it, similar to how I could flash it onto a different device with the same chip?

I have been looking into different software such as OVPsim(which is a "full system simulator" and Qemu, though I am unsure if they can run the full dump directly.

Can anyone shed some light on this, it can be confusing looking at everything.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sure, there are hardware emulators for such CPUs/systems. If you are willing to spend some 10k€.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run embedded-Linux systems under Qemu in the past, but they generally don't get far. Generally they give you an emulation of the CPU core, enough to boot the kernel, but no emulation of the "special sauce" around said CPU (e.g. SoCs may have timers, GPIOs, I/O interfaces and a whole host of other things).

If I was dead-set on doing this, I'd grab an emulator for the CPU core and probably write my own. How I did it would depend on what I was emulating - either MESS for older 8/16/32-bit platforms, or Qemu for modern-day kit.

Be wary of expecting too much from these systems. They're great for algorithm development and testing (and to a lesser extent "black box" automated testing) but there's a point at which you just plain need the hardware.